# Why wont JQuery hide/show elements on my web page and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem that has just now started happening for no reason. I'm playing around with a block that detects whether you are using Adblock. It sets a variable, `var canRunAds = true;` in a file titled `ads.js` which is not really ads but all adblockers will block it regardless. Next, somewhere in `index.html` tests to see if `canRunAds` is defined or not like this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/ads.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if( window.canRunAds === undefined ){
      $("#adblock_off").hide();
      $(".adblock_off").hide();
      console.debug("adblock enabled");
    }
    else {
      $("#adblock_on").hide();
      $(".adblock_on").hide();
      console.debug("adblock disabled/nonexistant");
    }
  </script>
  <div>
    <img src="../images/adblock_off.png" id="adblock_off"></img>
    <img src="../images/adblock_on.png" id="adblock_on"></img>
    <p class="adblock_off">Thanks for disabling your adblock!</p>
    <p class="adblock_on">Disable your adblock, no ads here!<p>
  </div>
</body>
```

This has always worked for me, however it has stopped working. The script runs the `console.debug` and it shows up in the console, but the elements wont hide. Any explaination?

PS: This is all documented at this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/legoman8304/JQuery-Error)

Comment: Dont think `canRunAds ` is a global variable

Comment: You're executing your JS logic before the DOM has been loaded. Either move it to the end of the `body`, or place it in a document.ready event handler

Comment: I can't see how this code worked before and then just stopped.